# ngx-formly with asyncValidators: Show some information/style while validation is running

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-formly

I am successfully using an asyncValidator for a password field to check the password's hash against a Rest Service.

It is working just fine, but sometimes it just takes "some time" for the async call to finish. I'd like to capture the state of "currently validating" and show some information on the field (e.g. a loading gif or a specific CSS style).

Is there any "hook" I could attach to in order to show information while async validator is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Form fields that are being validated with an async validator will also
>   have an ng-pending class while validation is pending. This makes it
>   easy to style fields that are currently pending validation

Using FormControl pending property

```
 <div *ngIf="myForm.get('email').pending">
    Loading...
  </div>
```

or

```
  <div *ngIf="myForm.get('email').status === 'PENDING'">
    Loading...
  </div>
```

Ref:https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/